# React dispatch from reducer firing twice

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

Whenever I call a function from the reducer, it gets called once the first time, and then twice every other time.
Here's the code:

reducer.js:

```
import data from './data'

export const initialState = {
    notes: data,
    filter: '',
};


export const setFilter = filter => ({ type: 'setFilter', filter });
export const createNote = id => ({ type: 'createNote', id })
export const deleteNote = note => ({ type: 'deleteNote', note })

export const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'setFilter':
            return { ...state, filter: action.filter };
        case 'createNote':
            console.count('Create note fired')
            state.notes.push({
                id: action.id,
                tags: [],
                content: ""
            })
            return { ...state }

        case 'deleteNote':
            return {
                ...state,
                notes: state.notes.filter((note) => note.id !== action.note.id)
            }


        default: return state;
    }
};
```

The component that calls the delete method:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { deleteNote } from "../../state/reducer";
import { useStateValue } from "../../state/StateContext";

import './Body.css'

import { Card, Badge } from 'react-bootstrap'


const Body = ({ notes }) => {
    let [state, dispatch] = useStateValue();
    return (
        <div className="Body">
            {
                notes.map(note =>
                    <Card key={note.id} className="Card">
                        <Card.Body className="CardText HideScrollbar">
                            <Card.Text>{note.content}</Card.Text>
                        </Card.Body>
                        <Card.Footer>
                            {note.tags.map(tag =>
                                <Badge variant="primary">
                                    {tag} </Badge>)}
                        </Card.Footer>
                        <div className="DeleteButton" onClick={() => dispatch(deleteNote(note))}>
                            <svg className="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path d="M10.185,1.417c-4.741,0-8.583,3.842-8.583,8.583c0,4.74,3.842,8.582,8.583,8.582S18.768,14.74,18.768,10C18.768,5.259,14.926,1.417,10.185,1.417 M10.185,17.68c-4.235,0-7.679-3.445-7.679-7.68c0-4.235,3.444-7.679,7.679-7.679S17.864,5.765,17.864,10C17.864,14.234,14.42,17.68,10.185,17.68 M10.824,10l2.842-2.844c0.178-0.176,0.178-0.46,0-0.637c-0.177-0.178-0.461-0.178-0.637,0l-2.844,2.841L7.341,6.52c-0.176-0.178-0.46-0.178-0.637,0c-0.178,0.176-0.178,0.461,0,0.637L9.546,10l-2.841,2.844c-0.178,0.176-0.178,0.461,0,0.637c0.178,0.178,0.459,0.178,0.637,0l2.844-2.841l2.844,2.841c0.178,0.178,0.459,0.178,0.637,0c0.178-0.176,0.178-0.461,0-0.637L10.824,10z"></path>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                    </Card>
                )

            }
        </div>
    )
}
Body.propTypes = {
    notes: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
}
export default Body
```

Any kind of help would be really helpful, please tell me if there's any file missing or if I implemented the reducer in the wrong way, what I did was mostly following notes from a friend's University professor

Answer (score 0):

make seperate action file. And get that action from redux through mapDispatchToProps in your component , where you want to dispatch that action.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setProfileDialog: ProfileAction.setProfileDialog,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that reducers must be pure. When react is in 'strict-mode' it will fire reducers twice to ensure that the result is the same both times. Mutating the original state will cause unwanted side effects.

Changing:

```
case 'createNote':
    console.count('Create note fired')
    state.notes.push({
       id: action.id,
       tags: [],
       content: ""
       })
    return { ...state }
```

To:

```
case 'createNote':
    const notes = [
        ...state.notes,
        {
            id: action.id,
            tags: [],
            content: "",
        }
    ]
    return {...state, notes}
```

Should fix your example.